# What is the reason that salesforce introduced Mixed DML Exception?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, batch

I attended an interview in the past and some questions really left me wondering why salesforce behaves the way it does. I am seeking answers to these questions, mostly every blog talks about how to avoid these errors and what is the workaround, but not why Salesforce made a particular behavior. I can recall a few of those questions:

1. What would have happened if Salesforce would have allowed a non setup and setup object DML operation in one transaction? Why `MIXED_DML` exception had to be introduced?
2. Why cannot we call a batch from another batch class in the `Start` method but only from the `Finish` method?
3. Why Apex calls are always asynchronous from LWC?

I have always known the workarounds to the technical blockers but these questions gave me another perspective to think about. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Answer to 1** is given in documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm

```
This restriction exists because some sObjects affect the user’s access to 
records in the org. You must insert or update these types of sObjects in a 
different transaction to prevent operations from happening with incorrect 
access-level permissions. For example, you can’t update an account and a user 
role in a single transaction.
```

**Some detailed explanation as requested :**

Lets say you insert an Account (`A1`), and account is Private shared only with UserRole specific to 'Role1'. So after Account insertion, salesforce runs its sharing recalculation and no users got access except the person inserting the account. After that in same transaction you inserted a new User with role 'Role1', now salesforce again fires its recalculation logic but is not able to find `A1` because that is not yet committed to DB. And thus the other user never gets access to `A1`, until again an update happens.

**Answer 2**

Its because to control recursiveness.
If salesforce would have allowed batch getting called from `start`  metthod. Nothing stops developer to rerun the same batch again from start. Which is an infinite batch loop.

**Some detailed explanation as requested :**

```
global class LeadProcessor implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Database.executeBatch(new LeadProcessor());
        String queryStr = 'SELECT Id, LeadSource FROM Lead';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(queryStr);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records) {

        // Some Logic
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Some Logic
    }
}
```

Here `Database.executeBatch(new LeadProcessor());` like can cause infinite loop.

**Answer 3** :
Any calls from LWC to apex always is async.
As we know salesforce fetches everything in realtime via rest calls (internal js files, css, page layouts etc). The Apex calls are also made using rest api. Each browser has some limitation of how many concurrent network calls can be made.
As apex can contain some heavy calculations, it can stop other HTTP connections if made in a sync manner. Thus the apex calls are actually enqueued in the browser and tt gets executed based on priority (this priority is based on many factors).
When the data is received back from Apex then your Promise `then` gets called.
If this is made sync, then it will block other threads to be executed

Comment: For #3, it's not just that it blocks other callouts, but rather that synchronous calls block the UI thread, meaning the app is completely blocked from anything, clicks, etc, until the call completes.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for improving the answer as always.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @NagendraSingh. I am still trying to wrap my head around 1 & 2, could you please help me with more elaboration. Thanks again.

Comment: @AyushGoyal Explained point 2 with example.

Comment: @AyushGoyal I tried adding an explanation for point 1 too. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @NagendraSingh. It now makes much more sense and gives a better picture. For Answer 2, what if I am not calling the same batch in the start method but some other batch class instance?

Comment: @AyushGoyal What if from that other batch `start` method you again run `LeadProcessor` again. This will still create infinite loop. `LeadProcessor -> Other Batch Start method -> Again Leadprocessor may be scheduled from this start method` Salesforce wont know that and wont know the dependency. So they have restricted calling batch from `start` method.

Comment: I am just wondering, what if I execute another batch from LeadProcessor start method, without calling LeadProcess again. Why isn't that allowed?

Comment: The reason is given above, as salesforce wont be able to keep a track whether you are calling same batch or different batch, because batch can even be called dynamically by converting a string into a class. So salesforce has stopped calling any batch from `start` method.